# How to store temp generated output in SQL into Table

Tags: sql, mariadb

i have a sql statement, which the result of caclulations i want to write into a table.

i got an result for temp. But unluckily i cant transfer these results into a new table, because its saying that temp is not defined.

```sql
SELECT BUM.LMISTAT_import.UhrzeitBeginn, BUM.LMISTAT_import.UhrzeitEnde,BUM.LMISTAT_import.DatumEnde,BUM.LMISTAT_import.DatumBeginn,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CAST(CONCAT(RIGHT(BUM.LMISTAT_import.DatumBeginn,2),'-',MID(BUM.LMISTAT_import.DatumBeginn,4,2),'-',LEFT(BUM.LMISTAT_import.DatumBeginn,2)) AS DATETIME),
CAST(CONCAT(RIGHT(BUM.LMISTAT_import.DatumEnde,2),'-',MID(BUM.LMISTAT_import.DatumEnde,4,2),'-',LEFT(BUM.LMISTAT_import.DatumEnde,2)) AS DATETIME)) AS temp 
FROM BUM.LMISTAT_import;
INSERT INTO BUM.LMISTAT_import(BUM.LMISTAT_import.factor)
VALUES (temp)
;
```

actural SQL Result = "1054: Unknow column temp in field list";

the expected result is, that the table ..._import.factor is filled with values from temp.

Comment: updated its mariadb

Comment: Can you share `BUM.LMISTAT_import` definition?

Comment: And what it means "the table ..._import.factor is filled with values ", `UPDATE` or `INSERT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `create table as`?

```
CREATE TABLE temp AS
    SELECT i.UhrzeitBeginn, i.UhrzeitEnde,
           i.DatumEnde, i.DatumBeginn,
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, 
                         CAST(CONCAT(RIGHT(i.DatumBeginn, 2), '-', MID(i.DatumBeginn,4,2), '-', LEFT(i.DatumBeginn,2)) AS DATETIME),
                         CAST(CONCAT(RIGHT(i.DatumEnde, 2), k'-', MID(i.DatumEnde, 4, 2), '-', LEFT(i.DatumEnde,2)) AS DATETIME)
                        ) AS temp 
    FROM BUM.LMISTAT_import i;
```

Comment: no i just want to add the result temp into an existing table BUM.LMISTAT_import. There is a field called factor, and temp=> factor ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [SELECT...INTO](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/selectinto/).

In your first query, "AS temp" creates an alias for your result set, not a column list, which "VALUES (...)" requires, but which won't work anyway here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the syntax

```
INSERT INTO temp (a,b,c)
    SELECT x,y,z ...;
```

Or even

```
CREATE TABLE temp (a,b,c)
    SELECT x,y,z ...;
```

Try to go back into `DatumBeginn` and store it as a `DATE` that is yyyy-mm-dd, not some other form.

Failing that, use [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) as a much more concise way to parse malformed date strings.

And a properly formed string does not need `CAST( ... AS DATE)`